# Nginx doesn't start after installation

Tags: apache-2.2

I've tried to install nginx on my vps buy following this steps

```
cd /usr/local/src

wget http://nginxcp.com/latest/nginxadmin.tar 

tar xf nginxadmin.tar

cd publicnginx

./nginxinstaller install
```

finally the apache in tweak setting checked working on port 8081 but the server still gives errors and nginex status is `down`.

this is the error when i restart apache from ssh

```
Restarting nginx daemon: nginxnginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:80 failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol) already running.
```

I'm using vps centos 5 whm cpanel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i fixed it

my vps is ipv4 not ipv6 so i changed  `[::]:80` to  `80` in ngnix config file and its working fine :)

Answer (score 4):

Someone seems to have disabled IPv6 on your server. Re-enable it and try again.

Comment: how to i do this ? what file i have to edit t?

Comment: @user3059001 please don't take this the wrong way, but if you're not familiar with how to enable/disable IPv6 on your particular server/operating system you have no business administering the system -- find someone with the requisite experience and skills to assist you.